# "Authentication failed" issue while publishing a xamarin ios using VS2019

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019, app-store-connect, visual-studio-mac

trying to publish a Xamarin IOS app to appstore. I am using VS2019. When i publish the app, i am getting the error:
"Publishing failed"
"Authentication failed"[image]

Comment: did you verify that your credentials are correct?  Did you try more than once to verify it's not a transient error?

Comment: what do you mean by credentials? i have tried more than one almost 10 times to publish the app to appstore and the same error

Comment: I'm getting the same error, so I wonder if it's a bug in the latest version of Visual Studio for Mac.